# Bones keeps on messing up my model?

Tags: modeling, animation, bones

So I downloaded a beautiful anime base from ALexzart on Sketchfab

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/anime-girl-model-base-free-5a1ef64055c748fd94447adbfa5a88a2

But when I wanted to add bones to it and animate it, it completely messes up the body.
When I move the arms, it moves the head too.
I really don't know what to do now.

This doesn't just happen to this model, it happens to models I made myself too.
Is there a setting I accidentally changed?
I tried to load the default settings, but it keeps on happening.

I also tried to solve it with weight paint, but that messes up the body even more.

Thanks for reading and I hope someone can help me

[image]

[image]

Here's the file:
[image]

Comment: Did you use automatic weighting? I think you should upload your file for inspecting.

Comment: I added the blend file, I hope someone can help me fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the mesh and use Alt P to remove the parenting.

Select the object and (in object mode) apply rot and scale (Ctrl A - rot and scale).

Do the same with the armature object.

This is a good habit that will set your rot and scale to default (0,0,0 and 1,1,1) without modifying the objects, and it's always a must if you want to use automatic functions and addons.

Then select the mesh and (in edit mode) select all and recalculate normals (Ctrl N).

Now select the mesh, shift select the armature and press Ctrl P - with automatic weights.

This procedure leads to a better starting point, but consider that it will be very difficult to animate your model without any IK device.

Search for IK tutorials or watch the complete human rigging free course on You Tube by Nathan Vegdahl.

[image]

Comment: This worked! I cannot thank you enough! I've had this problem for so long, I'm so happy it finally got fixed! Again, thank you so so much!!